# Python callback for a multiprocess Queue or Pipe

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, multiprocessing

Is there a way to create a callback that executes whenever something is sent to the main process from a child process initiated via `multiprocessing`? The best I can think of thus far is:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import threading
import time    

class SomeProcess(mp.Process):
    def run(self):
        while True
            time.sleep(1)
            self.queue.put(time.time())

class ProcessListener(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            value = self.queue.get()
            do_something(value)

if __name__ = '__main__':
    queue = mp.Queue()
    sp = SomeProcess()
    sp.queue = queue
    pl = ProcessListener()
    pl.queue = queue
    sp.start()
    pl.start()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No there is no other clean way to do so than the one you already posted.

This is how `concurrent.fututes.ProcessPoolExecutor` and `multiprocessing.Pool` are actually implemented. They have a dedicated thread which drains the tasks/results queue and run any associated callback.

If you want to save some resource, you can use a [`SimpleQueue`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.SimpleQueue) in this case.